# GraphQL-Ruby: Custom Logic on Type Resolution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, graphql-ruby

My team's been working with GraphQL Ruby, and we've found use cases for applying scopes and sorting through our queries, and have been writing the same code over and over in several places.

I'm wondering, is there a way to implement resolution logic for a type anywhere it is used? I want to add filtering and sorting arguments on every field that returns a specific type without having to write additional boiler plate whenever I return it from a field. In the example below, I would wrap it with a GraphQL::Function, and the sorting and filtering arguments are passed in on `args`. I'd like to not have to use the function every time, but just have the type implement the ability to use those arguments for its own resolution.

`field :institutionUser, Types::InstitutionUserType do
    with_filtering(resolve ->(obj, args, ctx) { 
        ....resolution logic
    })
end`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use a Resolver.

```
field :institutionUser, resolver: Resolvers::InstitutionUser
...
module Resolvers
  class InstitutionUser < GraphQL::Schema::Resolver
    type Types::InstitutionUser

    def resolve
      ...resolution logic
    end
  end
end
```

https://graphql-ruby.org/fields/resolvers.html